# Dynamically change MasterPage and ContentPlaceHolderID of asp content tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page which initially inherited from MastePage.master . And I want to use the same page but with different masterpage(MasterPage2.master) at some other place in my project. For that I am using the following code.

```
private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Update"].ToString() == "New")
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "MasterPage2.master";
            Content con = new Content();
            con = (Content)this.FindControl("Content1");
            this.Content1.ContentPlaceHolderID = "ContentPlaceHolder2";
        }
    }
```

I am also trying to set the asp content tag's ContentPlaceHolderID to ContentPlaceHolder2 which is from MasterPage2.master. Initially it was ContentPlaceHolder1.

But I am getting null value at  con = (Content)this.FindControl("Content1");

Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, Pages do not "inherit" from Master pages. They have a base type they inherit from already. They simply reference a master page and render within it.

Comment: So How do I reference same page to use different master page with getting error like this ---  Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'ContentPlaceHolder1' in the master page 'MasterPage2.master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.

Answer (score 2):

Page internally stores in private '_contentTemplateCollection' hashtable. it uses ContentPlaceHolderID property as key and stores special class (that will be used to build/initialize Content tag) as a value
 - so to change ContentPlaceHolderID value (defined within markup) you need to modify this hashtable, remove old entry linked with old Id and add other entry with new Id
 - you need to change ContentPlaceHolderId before creating master page otherwise an exception will be thrown in runtime
 - best place to change Ids is Page 'preinit' event and if it is better to change Ids before change master page (if you will change master page at runtime)

To change ContentPlaceHolderID of Content tag, you can use following function in Page PreInit event

```
public static void AssignContentToNewPlaceHoldersWithinPage(Page pPage, string pOldId, string pNewId)
{
    if (pPage == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pOldId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pNewId))
    {
        return;
    }
    // Try to get a reference to private hashtable using fasterflect free reflection library in codeplex (http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/)
    // you can replace following line with standard reflection APIs
    var lTmpObj = pPage.TryGetFieldValue("_contentTemplateCollection");
    if (lTmpObj != null && lTmpObj is Hashtable)
    {
        var _contentTemplateCollection = lTmpObj as Hashtable;

        if (_contentTemplateCollection.ContainsKey(pOldId) && !_contentTemplateCollection.ContainsKey(pNewId))
        {
            var lTemplate = _contentTemplateCollection[pOldId];
            _contentTemplateCollection.Add(pNewId, lTemplate);
            _contentTemplateCollection.Remove(pOldId);
        }

    }
}
```

- function parameter are
- pPage is reference to page instance contains content tag
- pOldId is ContentPlaceHolderId property value in markup - the Id you want to change
- pNewId is the new Id you want to use

I hope that my answer will be useful and I am sorry if my English language is not good

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically change the Master Page at runtime, but you need to use the same ContentPlaceHolder IDs. That way, your pages will work with either Master Page without adding extra code to change the IDs at runtime.

```
private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Update"].ToString() == "New")
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "MasterPage2.master";
    }
}
```

You can even test that your page will work with either Master Page in the Visual Studio design/markup view by changing the `MasterPageFile` in the `<% Page %>` directive  in the .aspx markup.

Answer (score 0):

The Master Page can be changed by overriding OnPreInit.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/MyOther.Master";
}
```

But for the ContentPlaceHolders I would suggest to create new ContentPlaceHolders with the same name in both of your MasterPages.